# Counting Sort - Can't understand why my algorithm is not working

Tags: python, algorithm

I am struggling with building a counting sort algorithm for the past 3 hours. I understand the concept and I can sort an array using the counting sort algorithm on paper with no problem. The problem is when trying to translate the steps from paper into code, my algorithm fails. The program breaks with error message "index out of bound". To understand the error, I used print functions to view the results at each iteration. The results were incorrect. What is the problem with the algorithm?

```
def count_sort(array):
    minArr = min(array)
    maxArr = max(array)

    sumArray = [0 for _ in range(minArr, maxArr+1)]

    for i in range(len(array)):
        sumArray[array[i] - 1] += 1
    print(sumArray)

    sumCount = []
    sumCount.append(sumArray[0])
    for i in range(1, len(sumArray)):
        sumCount.append(sumArray[i] + sumCount[i-1])
    print(sumCount)

    sortedArray = [0 for _ in range(len(array))]
    for i in range(len(array)):
        sortedArray[sumCount[array[i]] - 1] = array[i]
        sumCount[array[i]] -= 1
    print(sortedArray)
```

Comment: Which line causes the out of bounds?  What is the value that causes the out of bounds?

Comment: `sortedArray[sumCount[array[i-1]] - 1] = array[i]` is the line. I'm trying with the array `[1, 3, 2, 9, 7]`

Comment: for integers, you can do `[0]*len(array)` instead of `[0 for _ in range(len(array))]`

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: first try to sort a 2-element list and see what happens.

Comment: Still getting index out of range

Comment: Have you stepped through your code line-by-line in a debugger and viewed the contents of each variable at each line, including the one that it crashes on? If not, I'd recommend getting an IDE that allows you to do such a thing, and then learning how to do it, since it's one of the most basic, fundamental aspects of debugging any application.

Answer (score 0):

this line is a problem:
        sortedArray[sumCount[array[i]] - 1] = array[i]

I think you need to shift array[i] down by one? In the last iteration of your example array[4] = 9, so it tries to set sortedArray[sumcount[9] - 1]. sumcount's index goes from 0 through 8, so 9 is out of range. Changing to sortedArray[sumcount[array[i]-1]-1] should fix it i think.

The nested list adds confusion and makes it harder to spot this. Break it up and use variables instead of trying to do it on one line if you are having trouble. Much easier to debug. You add print statements to print the values at each step so you know which list and index cause the out of bounds error

```
my_length = len(array)
print(f'for i in range({my_length}):')
for i in range(my_length):
    print(f'x = array[{i}]')
    x = array[i]
    print(f'y = sumCount[{x}] - 1')
    y = sumCount[x] - 1
    print(f'sortedArray[{y}] = {x}')
    sortedArray[y] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
sortedArray[sumCount[array[i]] - 1] = array[i]
sumCount[array[i]] -= 1
```

by

```
sortedArray[sumCount[array[i]-1]-1] = array[i]
sumCount[array[i]-1]-= 1
```